# OData Query Filter Inside PowerApps

Tags: filter, odata, powerapps

I am trying to run a Power Automate Flow that has an Odata Filter query inside of PowerApps.[Power Automate Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCgGm.jpg)

Here is what my Odata Query Filter looks like in PowerApps:

ExportDiscrepancyReport.Run(cr73b_weekno eq 16)

16 represents the week number. Instead of hardcoding 16, I want to refer to a text input control that has the week number. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

you could easily modify the flow so that instead of passing the whole query filter from Power Apps, you would pass only the number of the week. Then your OData filter would look something like this:

*cr73b_weekno eq* *{HERE WILL BE PASSED ARGUMENT VALUE FROM POWER APPS}*

Since cr73b_weekno column will not change I guess, there is no point of passing the whole filter string from power apps - pass only the value you want to use in the filter.

Comment: I should have mentioned that there are multiple filter queries in my PowerApps. That's why I need to pass that whole filter query in PowerApps.

Comment: I kinda misread what you are trying to achieve - so the problem is that you are not sure how to refer to a component in the Power Apps itself, right? Every input has its name, so changing from example "16" to name of the input should work for you - it should glow with some kind of color when a reference to the input is made

Comment: I know how to refer to a component. It's not working because im not getting the string syntex correct. For example, startswith would look something like this: "startswith(cr73b_employee,'" & textinput &"')

Comment: Aah alright cool. but why do you use the & symbols? startswith(cr73b_employee,'textinput') where textinput is the value passed from Power Apps should work. Or even if the textinput is already a string, try remove '' arout the textinput symbols.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you are trying to pass the "Number" entered in text input inside canvas Power Apps to your Power automate flow.

So, run your Power automate flow from Power Apps using formula like:

```
ExportDiscrepancyReport.Run("cr73b_weekno eq " & TextInput.Text)
```

**OR**:

```
ExportDiscrepancyReport.Run("cr73b_weekno eq " & Value(TextInput.Text))
```

If your `cr73b_weekno` is of type text in backend/data source, you may need to use formula like:

```
ExportDiscrepancyReport.Run("cr73b_weekno eq '" & TextInput.Text & "'")
```

---

Also, it is better to use the Number format for your text input control like if you need user input in number format only:

[image]